# Enable ListView Selection - Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I got in to weird problem, I can't click on my list view... I have implemented it in same way the way I was doing before but, thing is it is not working.

```
listTags.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                listTags.setSelection(position);
                Toast.makeText(getParent(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

I am extending Activity class

and hear is how i declare listview

```
listTags = (ListView) viewToLoad.findViewById(R.id.listPack);
```

hear is what i did in xml

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listPack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
```

This is just as normal as everywhere, I can't figure out wha tis wrong, please help me with this.

Thank you

Hear the code for adapter

```
adapter = new KeywordAdapter(getApplicationContext(), id,
                getLNApplication().getKeyworddetail());
listTags.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My KeywordAdapter class

```
public class KeywordAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public KeywordAdapter(Context context, int id, ArrayList<ArrayList<Keyword>> keywordList) {
        this.context = context;
        if (id >= keywordList.size()) {
            keyWordList = new ArrayList<Keyword>();
        } else
            keyWordList = keywordList.get(id);
    }

    // Implemented methods for BaseAdpter

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView tagName;
        //.... more code
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.package_tag_details, null, true);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tagName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tagName);
            //.... more code
            holder.layout = (LinearLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.tagName.setText(keyWordList.get(position).getName());
        ArrayList<Integer> rank = keyWordList.get(position).getRank();


        @SuppressWarnings("unused")

        holder.tagRank1.setText(rank.get(position));


        //.... more code

        return view;
    }

    public void forceReload() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Comment: i think that Your   list item seleced but in problem in Toast's context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the item you have placed in listView, Make all items as `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: you mean the item which is in custom view

Comment: yeh the item in the custum view..suppose u r using TextView make it android:focusable="false"

Comment: I have posted the answer... I was having scrollView inside of that custom view

Answer (score 1):

Just change following in your code.

```
listTags = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPack);
```

Are you sure android:layout_width supports "match_parent"? Please look into console.
May this help you.

Comment: list is displaying perfectly but what went wrong is I don't have click event is not called

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see you setting the adapter i.e. **listTags.setAdapter(?);**

```
    Try this code (works for me):

    // MainActivity

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

           final ListView listTags = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPack);
           listTags.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, mStrings));
           listTags.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                       int position, long id) {
                   listTags.setSelection(position);
    //               Toast.makeText(getParent(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           });



        }


         private String[] mStrings = {

            "Comte", "Coolea", "Cooleney", "Coquetdale", "Corleggy", "Cornish Pepper",
            "Cotherstone", "Cotija", "Cottage Cheese", "Cottage Cheese (Australian)",
            "Cougar Gold", "Coulommiers", "Coverdale", "Crayeux de Roncq", "Cream Cheese",
            "Cream Havarti", "Crema Agria", "Crema Mexicana", "Creme Fraiche", "Crescenza",
            "Croghan", "Crottin de Chavignol", "Crottin du Chavignol", "Crowdie", "Crowley",
            "Cuajada", "Curd", "Cure Nantais", "Curworthy", "Cwmtawe Pecorino",
           };

    // Main xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listPack"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

            </LinearLayout>

    // list_item.xml // layout

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was one problem with the custom view of list view
I have used horizontal scrollView inside the view I removed that and now problem is solved

Comment: but if you removed android:focusable="false" from ur other view i dont think it will work

Comment: no,it is working... I haven't use android:focusable="false" before in any of the list view that i have used.

Comment: what kind of view you are having in your view

Comment: I have image view and textView and in my case if i dont use that then its not working..thats whay i need to used it

Comment: No i also have the imageview and textview, but i don't use it, I think that is needed only when button is in place... do you have clikevent for the image